# How to split a string using 2 parameters - python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if there was a way to use a .split() function to split a string up using 2 parameters.

For example in the maths equation:

x^2+6x-9

Is it possible to split it using the + and -?
So that it ends up as the list:
[x^2, 6x, 9]

Comment: `split().split()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that responds - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Aha, you are right of course. Why do you insist on using `split()`?

Comment: Are you ultimately looking for an arbitrary number of split characters? In that case, you should definitely use the `regex` module.

Comment: I'm fairly new to python so didn't know any other way of phrasing my question

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: Thanks i'll give regex a try

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use regx for solve your problem.

Comment: I'll upvote if you give a solution to the example at hand.

Comment: @Tobias I have not know too much about python . In Java this problem easily solved by regex .  http://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/re/python-re-exercise-47.php

Answer (score 0):

Since `.split()` returns a list, you'd have to iterate over the returned list one more time. This function (below) lets you `split` an arbitrary number of times, but as mentioned in another answer, you should consider using the `re` (regular expressions) module.

```
from itertools import chain


def split_n_times(s, chars):
    if not chars:
        # Return a single-item list  if chars is empty
        return [s]

    lst = s.split(chars[0])
    for char in chars:
        # `chain` concatenates iterables
        lst = chain(*(item.split(char) for item in lst))

    return lst
```

The regex version would be considerably shorter.

Answer (score 0):

This will do want you are requesting in the question

```
def multisplit(text, targets):
    input = []
    output = [text]
    for target in targets:
        input = output
        output = []
        for text in input:
            output += text.split(target)
    return output
```

Learning regex will probably help you do what you are intending to do. Play around with something like `[+-][^+-]*` over at https://regex101.com/ to get a better feel for how they work.

Comment: Thanks so much, i'll give regex ago